# mock patching python instance method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest.mock

There are many examples online and in the docs of patching static methods on classes, or mocking the entire class. What I want to do is create a new method on an existing class which is in a library that I do not own - [requests.Response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response).

I tried the code below but it doesn't appear to work

```
import requests  # has requests.Response class
from unittest.mock import patch


def foo(self):
    print("foo called")
    return self.text

patch.object(requests.Response, "foo", foo)

# many tests down here which get a response object and call response.foo()
```

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: You aren't patching an existing attribute name; you are adding a *new* one. `requests.Response.foo = foo` should work.

Comment: @chepner That should work, but it will not remove the modification after the test. It is always better to keep the test self contained.

Comment: That's what fixtures are for.

Comment: You might try patching `requests.Response` itself with a `Mock` object that wraps the real module, then configure that mock with a `foo` attribute that calls your function.